# Cannot Initialize Array with Constant Variable... WHY?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I'm fairly new to programming and I am having trouble initializing an array with a const int. so far for the code I have is this:

```
int temp = 0;
temp += valuesVec.size();
int SIZE = temp; 
int valuesArray[SIZE];
```

I am trying to make an array with the same number of elements as a vector that read a file and store all the values. the errors it gives me are:

```
Error   1   Expected constant expression.
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    
Error   3   error C2133: 'valuesArray' : unknown size   
Error   4   IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value
```

all the errors lead back to:    `int valuesArray[SIZE];`
printing SIZE gave me the value 1118.

I know I am probably doing something stupid and probably forgot some fundamental rule but... Until someone points it out I will be pouring over my book.

Comment: What does "Constant Variable" mean to you?

Comment: Not the same thing it means to the compiler. :)

Comment: Use a std::vector. Use an array only if you have a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

Size of a static array can only be specified with a nonzero constant value. If on the compile time the size is unknown then you should use dynamic array.

```
int * valuesArray = new int [SIZE];
...
delete[] valuesArray;
```

Please make sure using proper delete[] operator.

Or better use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Remove the `new`/`delete` part, it makes this answer *worse*, not better. It’s error-prone, complicated and not necessary. And it certainly won’t help OP.

Comment: According to the author's proficiency was given the answer. STL might be confusing for him so far.

Comment: `new`/`delete` is *more* confusing. Despite what people think, the standard library is elementary C++. `new`/`delete` is not.

Answer (score 0):

`SIZE` is not a compile-time constant (at least not unless `valuesVec` is), so you can not statically declare an array with `SIZE` as its size.

You can try manually allocating it:

```
int* valuesArray = new int[SIZE];
```

if you remember to `delete[]` it. Or you can simply make another vector:

```
std::vector<int> valuesArray(SIZE);
```

Comment: Remove the `new`/`delete` part, it makes this answer *worse*, not better. It’s error-prone, complicated and not necessary. And it certainly won’t help OP.